# Show that there is a $C$ such that $\frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}} \leq C(\frac {1}{n^\alpha}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^\alpha})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> 1.(a) Show that if $\alpha>0$, then there is a constant $C$ such that for any $n\in \mathbb N$,
>
> $$\frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}} \leq C(\frac {1}{n^\alpha}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^\alpha})$$
> [Suggestion: Write
> $$\frac {1}{n^\alpha}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^\alpha}=\frac{1}{n^\alpha}[\frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^\alpha}}{\frac{1}{n}}],$$
> and estimate the expression in square brackets as converging to a derivative as $n\to\infty$]

In this equation, I am wondering if I set $C$ to be infinity then I can confirm that there is surely a $C$ that exist? Or if not, can anyone tell me how should I interpret this $C$?

Comment: The language of question implies they are looking for a finite $C$. I don't understand what you mean by "how should I interpret this $C$", so please explain.

Comment: "constant" means number, $\infty$ is not a number.

Comment: I think I am asking how do I use the below expression to find the C, but initially I thought C can be infinity and if C is infinity then it would work and i would not have to use the expression.. sorry fr my bad english

Comment: Regarding the [formatting and writing of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992), please do not force readers to click on an external link just in order to see what you are actually asking. We should be able to see what you are asking by looking at your post.

Comment: sorry , but when I uploaded a picture it changed it to that format.. what should I do sir

Comment: If $C$ were infinite, then there would be nothing to prove.  As a simple exercise in psychology, I think that it is sufficiently clear that $C$ is not infinite.  More generally, whenever an author writes "Let $C$ be a constant," it means that $C$ is a number **unless** the author explicitly says otherwise.

Comment: @JosephRock : fixed up your question, please use Mathjax instead of images, mathjax is much simpler than doing math.
Also include the source of the question, that is the book and page number please.

Comment: The exercise holds formally (modulo the usual convention in dealing with extended reals) for $C = \infty$, but it's trivial in that case and clearly not what the author had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

define a function $f:[1-\delta, +\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ (for some small $\delta>0$) as $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac {1}{x^{\alpha}}$ for some $\alpha>0$. Check for yourself that $f$ satisfies all the required conditions for mean value theorem.

so there is a point $c\in [n,n+1]$ satisfying 
$f(n+1)-f(n)=f'(c)= -\displaystyle\frac{1}{\alpha c^{1+\alpha}}$

consequently, $f(n)-f(n+1)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\alpha c^{1+\alpha}}\geq\displaystyle\frac{1}{\alpha (1+n)^{1+\alpha}}\geq (\displaystyle\frac{1}{\alpha n^{1+\alpha}}).(\displaystyle\frac{n}{n+1})^{1+\alpha}\geq (\displaystyle\frac{1}{\alpha n^{1+\alpha}}).(\displaystyle\frac{1}{2})^{1+\alpha}$

So, $C^{-1}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\alpha.2^{1+\alpha}}$ works $\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

We choose $\displaystyle C=1+\dfrac{1}{\alpha}$ if $\alpha\ge 1$ and $C=1+\dfrac{2}{\alpha(\alpha+1)}$ otherwise. The inequality $\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}}\le C\left(\dfrac{1}{n^\alpha}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^\alpha}\right)$
is equivalent to $$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^\alpha\ge\dfrac{C}{C-\frac{1}{n}}=1+\dfrac{1}{Cn-1}$$
and the left-handed side above, when $\alpha\ge 1$, is $\ge 1+\dfrac{\alpha}{n}$, thus, it suffices to show that $$1+\dfrac{\alpha}{n}\ge 1+\dfrac{1}{Cn-1}\Longleftrightarrow n\left(C-\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\right)\ge 1$$ which is true for $C$ we had chosen.

For the case $0< \alpha <1$ the left-handed side of the above inequality, according to Taylor expansion, is $1+\dfrac{\alpha}{n}+\dfrac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\left(\left(\dfrac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{3!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)\left(\dfrac{4n+(\alpha-3)}{4n}\right)\dots\right)$ which in the last bracket is greater than or equal to zero each term, for $\alpha$ in this range.

We suffice to prove that $\displaystyle \dfrac{\alpha}{n}\left(1-\dfrac{1-\alpha}{2n}\right)=\dfrac{\alpha}{n}\left(1+\dfrac{\alpha-1}{2n}\right)\ge \dfrac{1}{Cn-1}$ for the chosen $C$
we have $\displaystyle 1-\dfrac{1-\alpha}{2n}\ge\dfrac{1+\alpha}{2}$ and plug it in, the inequality follows $\Box$

Comment: The inequality $\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^\alpha   \ge 1 + \frac{\alpha }{n}$ is true only for $\alpha \geq 1$. If $0<\alpha<1$, it is reversed.

Comment: Thank you, I hope I edited to the right version.

Comment: Your claim is that for $0<\alpha<1$, $$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^\alpha   \ge 1 + \frac{1}{{n^\alpha  }} \Leftrightarrow (1 + n)^\alpha   \ge 1 + n^\alpha,$$ which is not true (try it with, e.g.,  $\alpha=1/2$). However, by the concavity of the power function, $$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^\alpha   \ge \frac{1}{{2^{1 - \alpha } }}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{n^\alpha  }}} \right)
$$ for any positive $n$ and $0<\alpha<1$.